# How to get meaningful data from formdata with Java?

Tags: java, servlets, multipartform-data

I have a form like this :

```
  <form id="test" name="test" action="/pages/font/getFontTitle.jsp" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="dialog">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="prop"><td valign="top">Name</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
          <tr class="prop"><td valign="top"><input type="file" name="fname" size="62" value="" id="fname"/></td><td><span class="button"><s:submit/></span></td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div> 
  </form>
```

And my servlet look like this :

```
String contentType=request.getContentType(),Location="0.";
out.println("Done");
System.out.println("contentType = "+contentType);

  boolean isMultipart=ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);           // Check that we have a file upload request
  System.out.println("isMultipart = "+isMultipart);

  int formDataLength=request.getContentLength();                           // We are taking the length of Content type data
  byte dataBytes[]=new byte[formDataLength];
  System.out.println("dataBytes = "+dataBytes.length+"\n"+dataBytes.toString());

  java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]> ParameterMap=request.getParameterMap();
  Iterator it=ParameterMap.entrySet().iterator();
  while (it.hasNext())
  {
    Map.Entry pair=(Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey()+" = "+(pair.getValue()).toString());
//    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
  }
  System.out.println("request = \n"+request.getParameterNames().toString());

  if (isMultipart)
  {
    FileItemFactory factory=new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload=new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List items=null;
Location+="1.";
    try { items=upload.parseRequest(request); }
    catch (FileUploadException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    Location+="2.";
    Iterator itr=items.iterator();
    Location+="3.";
    while (itr.hasNext()) 
    {
        Location+="4.";
      FileItem item=(FileItem)itr.next();
      if (item.isFormField())
      {
        String name=item.getFieldName(),value=item.getString();
        System.out.println("name = "+name+"  value = "+value);
        Location+="5.";
      }
      else
      {
        try
        {
          Location+="6.";
          String itemName=item.getName(),savedFilePath=itemName;
          File savedFile=new File(savedFilePath);
          System.out.println("savedFile = "+savedFile.getAbsolutePath());
          item.write(savedFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      }
    }
  }
Location+="e.";

  out.println(" [ "+Location+" ]");
  out.flush();
```

The result I get was :

```
contentType = multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------15890672924370
isMultipart = true
dataBytes = 35909
[B@14d3ba9
name = [Ljava.lang.String;@187f9d7
request = 
java.util.Vector$1@23ca6e
```

dataBytes has a file in it, but it never got into the while (itr.hasNext()) loop, the jsp output was : Done [ 0.1.2.3.e. ] , Location 4,5,6 was never reached.

[1] Why ?
[2] How to turn "dataBytes = [B@14d3ba9 " into something readable or a file ?
[3] How to turn "name = [Ljava.lang.String;@187f9d7" into the original string value ?
[4] I'm using "(pair.getValue()).toString()", but why it's not a readable string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client will send the HTTP request body only once.

Your code is however trying to read the request body twice. The first time by the `getParameterMap()` call:

```
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]> ParameterMap=request.getParameterMap();
```

and the second time by Apache Commons FileUpload (which will face an empty request):

```
try { items=upload.parseRequest(request); }
```

This isn't going to work.

Use *either* the standard Servlet API methods, *or* Apache Commons FileUpload exclusively.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) - contains concrete examples of both the Commons FileUpload and standard Servlet API methods.

Answer (score 0):

use should use servelt 3.0 spec and annotate your servlet accordingly and then usin can user `request.getParts()` with all the multi-part data. Read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Subquestion 1,3,4: if you cannot use the file upload feature added in Servlet 3.0 I think you're better off using [Commons Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html), more or less the de facto standard for uploading files to servlets.  It's robust, well tested and just works.

Subquestion 2: the [Javadoc for ServletRequest's getParameterMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) states:

> Returns: an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names as keys
>   and parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter map are
>   of type String. **The values in the parameter map are of type String
>   array.**

Emphasis added: the values returned are arrays of Strings, not Strings.  That's why you get the strange output value.  Try

```
System.out.println( pair.getKey()+" = "+ pair.getValue()[0] );
```

But also consider using a logger in your servlets, it's better practice than dumping stuff in System.out

ps: use the code formatting feature that's probaby available in your IDE, your code is pretty hard to read.

Comment: Yes, it's this : System.out.println(pair.getKey()+" = "+((String[])pair.getValue())[0]);